# How to match array to hash in one step, and place it in Model instance method?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to tranform `Geo.Point` coordinates attribute contains `%Geo.Point{coordinates: {49.44, 17.87}, srid: nil}` after `Geo.JSON.encode`: `%{"coordinates" => [49.44, 17.87], "type" => "Point"}`
To following formula:

```
%{latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}
```

This is my current method, how to do it in one step?

```
%{"coordinates" => [latitude,longitude] } = Geo.JSON.encode(place.coordinates)
coordinates = %{latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}
```

How to place it in instance method, so that it will return new formula after call e.g `place.to_lat_lng`?

```
defmodule MyApp.Place do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "place" do
    field :coordinates, Geo.Point

    timestamps
  end
  def to_lat_lng do
    #...format coordinates
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to JSON encode. You can pass the Geo.Point as an argument to a function. I would do something like:

```
  def to_lat_lng(%Geo.Point{coordinates: {lat, long}}) do
    %{latitude: lat, longitude: long}
  end
```

Please note that this is not an instance method. It is simply a function. some other terminology things that you should know as it may help you with documentation: In elixir we have a list, not an array. We also use a map or a dict http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/maps-and-dicts.html